# Storing likes and follows informations in different models gives me error: most likely due to a circular import

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models: `Product` and `User`

```
class Product(models.Model):
    #here are information fields about Product

    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        User, related_name="product_likes", blank=True)

    object = models.Manager()
    productobjects = ProductObjects()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    #here are information fields about User

    followed = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product, related_name="followed_products", blank=True)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()
    object = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Inside `Product` I need to have a `likes` filed ManyToMany which store which users liked the product. Inside `User` I need to have `followed` field ManyToMany which store which products the user follow.

I have an error: `cannot import name 'Product' from partially initialized module 'product.models' (most likely due to a circular import)`. How can I fix it? Or maybe can I do this differently?

I think the problem is that inside `product.models` I import: `from users.models import User` and inside `users.models` I import: `from product.models import Product`.

(I am using the `likes` filed just to GET number of likes, but from `followed` I need to GET all the products that specified user follow and informations about them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Product` model needs to import the `User` model and vice versa. As a result the imports got stuck in an infinite loop.

You can however use a string literal to specify to what model your `ManyToManyField` is pointing. For example:

```
# no import of the models module where you define User

class Product(models.Model):
    #here are information fields about Product

    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        'app_name.User', related_name="product_likes", blank=True
    )
    # ⋮
```

Here *`app_name`* is the name of the app where you defined the (custom) user model.

Since it is (likely) the user model, you here can use the [**`AUTH_USER_MODEL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL):

```
# no import of the models module where you define User
from django.conf import settings

class Product(models.Model):
    #here are information fields about Product

    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="product_likes", blank=True
    )
    # ⋮
```